# ¿Cuándo emplear la palabra 'objeto' y objetivo' para expresar los ideales de un procedimiento?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, ambigüedad

Me surge la duda de si es correcto emplear la palabra "objeto" para referirse a algo que se quiere lograr al emplear una metodología para resolver un problema.

Aquí el caso: inicialmente se escribió "Este método se propuso con el **objeto** de representar gráficamente el estado de [...]", ¿Es correcto el uso de la palabra? ¿Sería mejor decir "Este método se propuso con el **objetivo** de representar gráficamente el estado de [...]"?

Answer (score 3):

*Objeto* y *objetivo* son sinónimos exactos en este caso. Para *[objeto](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QmweHtN)*, el Diccionario de la Real Academia Española incluye como definición:

> *Fin o intento a que se dirige o encamina una acción u operación.*

En el caso de *[objetivo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QmvS5XH)*, la definición simplemente dirige a la de *objeto*, de manera que da lo mismo utilizar uno u otro.

Por supuesto hay otros significados donde estas dos palabras no son sinónimas y por lo tanto no puede reemplazarse una por otra. Por ejemplo, es bastante diferente lanzar un proyectil contra un *objetivo* (es decir, contra un blanco determinado) y lanzar un proyectil contra un *objeto* (es decir, contra una cosa material inerte). Se puede usar *objeto* para referirse a la cosa que es afectada por una operación comercial (el objeto de un contrato de venta es aquello que se vende), pero no *objetivo* (si decimos "el objetivo de un contrato de venta" nos referimos a su propósito).